# Detect if a smartphone is in range

Tags: java, android, smartphone

I'm trying to design a simple app, which detects which devices are nearby using whatever sensors are enabled on the other devices (wifi, bluetooth, etc). Think of it as an app that can detect when the owner is close to the house and send a message to another device (e.g. raspberry PI or whatever) to automatically unlock the door.

1. Which sensors can be used?
2. Can uniquely identifiable information be obtained (such as device name, device Id, MAC address) without pairing/connecting?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Bluetooth.
1) Remove from paired list if both are in paired.
2) Scan for Bluetooth

```
 registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

and here you get nearby Devices

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        int  rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
         // Use this as signal(device is near or Far)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
};
```

Comment: OK, makes sense. I'm starting to realize that this won't work with the phone alone. I think I'll just use a keychain bluetooth tag, because the Bluetooth on the other phone might be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bluetooth

   Just like @Ganesh Pokale said, we can start bluetooth scanning first, if other's bluetooth is on and being able to be discovered, then we can receive the broadcast. To start discovery, use `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery`. In the action we received, we can get `BluetoothDevice` class, which contains devicename, bluetooth mac address and so on. I suggest you find more details in [Android API Guides Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).
2. WifiDirect

   WifiDirect is also called 'WIfi P2P', if other's WifiDirect is on, we can scan them, and get their information, but it's a little complicater than bluetooth. Firstly, we start scanning use
   `WifiP2pManager.discoverPeers`. This call is asynchronous and we need a broadcastreceiver to receive results. In the broadcastreceiver, if `action` equals `WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION`, then we can request available peers with `WifiP2pManager.requestPeers(mChannel, myPeerListListener)`. The `requestPeers()` method is also asynchrnous and we will get the device list in myPeerListListener. This list will contain `WifiP2pDevice` class, which contains devicename, wifip2p mac address and so on. I suggest you find more details in [Android API Guides WifiP2pManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html).